# Fluid dynamics continuity equation in not inertial reference frame

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, inertial-frames

I know that the "canonical" Navier-Stokes equations must be modified when the reference frame is not inertial (e.g. Coriolis force has to be taken into account).

Does the continuity equation (mass conservation equation) have to be modified as well in a not inertial frame, or does it retain its standard form?

Comment: It remains its standard form.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please sketch a proof of this or redirect me to a page where this fact is proven? I haven't found it anywhere